# How to rewrite IIF and dlookup function from Access in SQL Server as we have recently migrated from access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to rewrite the `IIF` and `dlookup` part of this query so its can work in SQL Server .

I would preferably like the `CASE` and `SELECT` statement as SQL Server doesn't have `dlookup` function  so code is not working . I have come up with a draft but if an expert can help with getting the code right

```
SELECT
ScopeHistory.ProjectReturnID,
ScopeHistory.ProjectID, 

--IIf([ScopeDate] Is Null,Null,

--DLookUp("QTR_ID","Quarters","QuarterNo = " & IIf(Month([ScopeDate])<4,4,IIf(Month([ScopeDate])<7,1,
--IIf(Month([ScopeDate])<10,2,3))) & "AND CalendarYear = " & Year([ScopeDate])))*1 AS [QTR Change Occurs], 
--IIf([Qtr Change Occurs]=[QtrID],1,0) AS [Change This Qtr], Month([ScopeDate]) AS test, 

FROM 
(((((ScopeHistory 
INNER JOIN Impact ON ScopeHistory.ImpactEndDate = Impact.ImpactID) INNER JOIN Impact AS Impact_1 ON ScopeHistory.ImpactCosts = Impact_1.ImpactID)
LEFT JOIN Impact AS Impact_2 ON ScopeHistory.ImpactStratOut = Impact_2.ImpactID) 
LEFT JOIN Impact AS Impact_3 ON ScopeHistory.ImpactStratOutNM = Impact_3.ImpactID) LEFT JOIN Impact AS Impact_4 ON ScopeHistory.ImpactStratOutM = Impact_4.ImpactID) 
LEFT JOIN Impact AS Impact_5 ON ScopeHistory.ImpactPeople = Impact_5.ImpactID
ORDER BY ScopeHistory.ProjectReturnID;
```

It's the code itself I need help with .

I came up with this but it's not quite right; if anyone can help spot where am wrong , it will be much appreciated.

```
CASE
 WHEN [ScopeDate] Is Null THEN NULL
 ELSE
 (SELECT qtr. QTR_ID, QuarterNo =  
   CASE
     WHEN  Month([ScopeDate])<4 THEN 4 
     WHEN  Month([ScopeDate])<7 THEN 1
     WHEN  Month([ScopeDate])<10 THEN 2  ELSE 3 
   END AS [QTR Change Occurs]
  FROM Quarters as qtr 
  INNER JOIN [ScopeHistory] sc 
    ON qtr.QTR_ID= sc.QTRID AND qtr.[CalendarYear] = Year([ScopeDate])*1

  CASE WHEN [QTR Change Occurs] =QTR_ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Change This Qtr],
```

Answer (score 0):

IIF() is supported in all supported versions of SQL Server (So I guess it got introduced in SQL Server 2012).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I checked the purpose of DLookup and you could use a user defined function or a correlated subquery but in all probability it is going to be simpler to join in the extra table required in the FROM clause.

Looking at your query I would investigate if

Datepart(qq, ScopeDate)

wouldn't end up with simpler and easier to understand code